# Finding standard deviation from proportions.

Tags: probability

There are 365 people. $1/6$ of the people eat $0$ cookies, $1/2$ eat $1$ cookie and $1/3$ eat $2$ cookies.

What is the probability that between 400 and 450 cookies are eaten?

What I've done so far:
$$
\frac16 \cdot 365 = 60.83, \frac12 \cdot 365 =182.5, \frac13 \cdot 365 = 121.67
$$
$$
Mean = (60.83 \cdot 0) + (182.5 \cdot 1) + (121.67 \cdot 2) = 425.84
$$

How do I find the standard deviation with the information given so that I can calculate $P( 400 \le x \le 450)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the problem is stated, this is not a probability theory problem. We will produce such a problem, but it will require considerable reinterpretation of the words.

Suppose that the probability that a randomly chosen person eats $0$ cookies is $1/6$, the probability she eats $1$ is $1/2$, and the probability she eats $2$ is $1/3$. There are $365$ randomly chosen people. Let $X$ be the number of cookies eaten. Find the mean and the variance of $X$.

Line up the people. Let $W_1$ be the number of cookies eaten by the first person, let $W_2$ be the number of cookies eaten by the second, and so on to $W_n$, where $n=365$. Then
$X=W_1+\cdots+W_n$. It follows that $E(X)=nE(W_1)$ and $\text{Var}(X)=n\text{Var}(W_1)$.
For the second result, we need to assume thst the $W_i$ are independent, which may not be reasonable.

Note that $E(W_1)=(0)(1/6)+(1)(1/2)+(2)(1/3)$ (this was in essence your calculation).

For the variance of $W_1$, note that this is $E(W_1^2)-(E(W_1))^2$. We already know the second term. To finish, note that $E(W_1^2)=(0^2)(1/6)+(1^2)(1/2)+(2^2)(1/3)$.

To find, approximately, the required probability, note that $X$ is the sum of a fairly large number of independent identically distributed random variables, with a not too weird distribution. So $X$ is approximately normal. We know its mean and variance.

We leave it to you to put the pieces together and do the calculation.

Comment: How did I miss your crossing the threshold into the frontiers of $300$K? I was sort of watching...but, oila! you accomplished this feat when I "wasn't watching!" Congratulations, André, for having accomplished this, and thank you for all your always-respectful-to-users answers (and comments, too)!

Comment: Thank you. I particularly appreciate the "respectful" part of the comment, since there you have set a standard that I cannot hope to match.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}=1
$$
there is no need to calculate probabilities. The number of cookies eaten is
$$
365\left(\frac{1}{6}\cdot0+\frac{1}{2}\cdot1+\frac{1}{3}\cdot2\right)=425.83...\,.
$$
To answer your questions:
$$
P(400\leq X\leq450)=1
$$
with $X$ being the number of cookies eaten and there is no need to calculate standard deviation.